# Flash Action Script: How do I extract variables from a text file line by line?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, actionscript

I have a text file that is in the format below.

39.570 -0.246 0.074 1.004 0
39.822 -0.344 0.094 0.887 0
40.083 -0.262 0.234 0.926 0
40.335 -0.457 0.160 0.813 0
40.578 -0.242 0.063 1.008 0
40.830 -0.285 0.172 0.988 0
41.082 -0.277 0.129 0.918 0
41.334 -0.332 0.145 0.996 0
41.586 -0.332 0.156 0.910 0
41.843 -0.340 0.160 0.941 0
42.092 -0.371 0.121 0.793 0

As you can see there are no distinguishing characters to split up the data into variables. What I need to do is split up each line into 5 separate variables

e.g.  39.570 -0.246 0.074 1.004 0

would be

var timestamp01= 39.570

var xaccel01= -0.246

var yaccel01= 0.074

var zaccel01= 1.004

var boardheat01= 0

and that would be repeated for each line until the end of the document with each variable having a different value depending on what line it's on e.g. timestamp02 would relate to the first number on line two e.g. 39.822

I keep finding parts of information but usually it ends up needing identifiers in the text file (&& and things like that).

Here is what I have so far:

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

movieClip_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_OpenFile);

var fl_OpenFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();    // FileStream used to read from the file
var fl_OpenFileChooser:File = File.documentsDirectory;  // Default to the documents directory
fl_OpenFileChooser.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fl_FileOpenSelected);

// Main function for opening a file
function fl_OpenFile(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_OpenFileChooser.browseForOpen("Select a text file.");
}

// Opens a FileStream object to read the file
function fl_FileOpenSelected(event:Event):void
{
    fl_OpenFileChooser = event.target as File;
    fl_OpenFileStream = new FileStream();
    fl_OpenFileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fl_FileReadHandler);

    fl_OpenFileStream.openAsync(fl_OpenFileChooser, FileMode.READ);
}

// Write data from the file to the Output Panel
function fl_FileReadHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var fileData:String = fl_OpenFileStream.readMultiByte(fl_OpenFileStream.bytesAvailable, File.systemCharset);
    // The data loaded from the file can now be used from the variable fileData.

    //Split the string by a newline character
var arLines:Array = fileData.split("n");

var x;


for each (var singleLine:String in arLines)
{
    //More code coming up
    x = String(arLines).substr(0,6)
    // This example code displays data from the file in the Output panel.
    outputMod.text = String(x);

}


    fl_OpenFileStream.close();
}
```

With x being the first bit of data on the first line. You will notice that my coding skills are pretty low but I learn quickly as long as I have a starting point. If anyone could shed some light on this problem or even point me in the right direction that would be brilliant.

Comment: You should be able to split each single line on the space character. x = singleLine.split(' '); var timestamp01 = x[0]; // etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with items that look the same you usually want to place them in some sort of container that you can iterate over (array/vector).

In this solution I did it with anonymous objects, but they could easily be extended into a class if you want.

```
function FileParser() {
    var input:String = "39.570 -0.246 0.074 1.004 0\n" + "39.822 -0.344 0.094 0.887 0\n" + "40.083 -0.262 0.234 0.926 0\n" + 
    "40.335 -0.457 0.160 0.813 0\n" + "40.578 -0.242 0.063 1.008 0\n" + "40.830 -0.285 0.172 0.988 0\n" + "41.082 -0.277 0.129 0.918 0\n" +
    "41.334 -0.332 0.145 0.996 0\n" + "41.586 -0.332 0.156 0.910 0\n" + "41.843 -0.340 0.160 0.941 0\n" + "42.092 -0.371 0.121 0.793 0";

    var data:Array = new Array();
    var rows:Array = input.split("\n");
    for (var i:int = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
    {
        var parts:Array = rows[i].split(" ");
        if (parts.length == 5) {
            data.push( {
                timestamp:parts[0],
                xAccel:parts[1],
                yAccel:parts[2],
                zAccel:parts[3],
                boardHeat:parts[4]
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error("Invalid number of values for row:" + rows[i]);
        }

    }

    trace("...iterating over data...");
    for (var j:int = 0; j < data.length; j++) 
    {
        trace("timestamp for item #" + j + "=" + data[j].timestamp);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
...iterating over data...
timestamp for item #0=39.570
timestamp for item #1=39.822
timestamp for item #2=40.083
timestamp for item #3=40.335
timestamp for item #4=40.578
timestamp for item #5=40.830
timestamp for item #6=41.082
timestamp for item #7=41.334
timestamp for item #8=41.586
timestamp for item #9=41.843
timestamp for item #10=42.092
```

Answer (score 0):

THis would do it in a normal Batch File... not sure about Actionscript.

I've added the `ECHO` lines at the bottom so you can check the output works as you need it by checking the file `Output.txt` that it will create.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET sourcefile=list01.txt
SET outputfile=output.txt

:start
SET count=000
FOR /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a IN (%sourcefile%) DO CALL :process1 %%a
PAUSE
GOTO :eof

:process1
SET /a count=%count%+1
SET timestamp%count%=%1
SET xaccel%count%=%2
SET yaccel%count%=%3
SET zaccel%count%=%4
SET boardheat%count%=%5
ECHO Row !count!>>%outputfile%
ECHO Time Stamp:!timestamp%count%! X-accel:!xaccel%count%! Y-accel:!yaccel%count%! Z-accel:!zaccel%count%!  Board Heat:!boardheat%count%!>>%outputfile%
GOTO :eof
```

Using your input list above, the output file from this batch would look like this...

```
Row 1
Time Stamp:39.570 X-accel:-0.246 Y-accel:0.074 Z-accel:1.004  Board Heat:0
Row 2
Time Stamp:39.822 X-accel:-0.344 Y-accel:0.094 Z-accel:0.887  Board Heat:0
Row 3
Time Stamp:40.083 X-accel:-0.262 Y-accel:0.234 Z-accel:0.926  Board Heat:0
Row 4
Time Stamp:40.335 X-accel:-0.457 Y-accel:0.160 Z-accel:0.813  Board Heat:0
Row 5
Time Stamp:40.578 X-accel:-0.242 Y-accel:0.063 Z-accel:1.008  Board Heat:0
Row 6
Time Stamp:40.830 X-accel:-0.285 Y-accel:0.172 Z-accel:0.988  Board Heat:0
Row 7
Time Stamp:41.082 X-accel:-0.277 Y-accel:0.129 Z-accel:0.918  Board Heat:0
Row 8
Time Stamp:41.334 X-accel:-0.332 Y-accel:0.145 Z-accel:0.996  Board Heat:0
Row 9
Time Stamp:41.586 X-accel:-0.332 Y-accel:0.156 Z-accel:0.910  Board Heat:0
Row 10
Time Stamp:41.843 X-accel:-0.340 Y-accel:0.160 Z-accel:0.941  Board Heat:0
Row 11
Time Stamp:42.092 X-accel:-0.371 Y-accel:0.121 Z-accel:0.793  Board Heat:0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use RegExp to match the pattern of data.

First of all, get all the lines. Following pattern is one of many possible solutions:

```
var reg1:RegExp = /[\d-. ]*[\n]{1}/g;
var lineArray:Array = yourString.match(reg1);
```

Now you have an array of lines, like this:

```
39.570 -0.246 0.074 1.004 0
,39.822 -0.344 0.094 0.887 0
,40.083 -0.262 0.234 0.926 0
,40.335 -0.457 0.160 0.813 0
,40.578 -0.242 0.063 1.008 0
,40.830 -0.285 0.172 0.988 0
,41.082 -0.277 0.129 0.918 0
,41.334 -0.332 0.145 0.996 0
,41.586 -0.332 0.156 0.910 0
,41.843 -0.340 0.160 0.941 0
```

Loop trough that array and for each loop create an object that would hold the data:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++)
{
    var line:String = lineArray[i];
    var dataObject:CustomDataObject = new CustomDataObject(); // create your own class, I named this CustomDataObject
    // here, break the line into smaller chunks that are separated by a space
    var variableArray:Array = line.split(" ");

    dataObject.yourVar1 = Number(variableArray[0]);
    dataObject.yourVar2 = Number(variableArray[1]);
    dataObject.yourVar3 = Number(variableArray[2]);
    dataObject.yourVar4 = Number(variableArray[3]);
    dataObject.yourVar5 = Number(variableArray[4]);
}
```

And that's it!